# PHP form handling, dataload

Tags: php, mysql

My main objective is loading the price(monto) when the product and the payment method is selected(Criterio de Cobro).
This by using a query, I can't find how to put product and payment method  variables for making the query of the final price.

```html
<label>Producto</label>
<select name="id_producto" class="input_form" id="idCategoriaProducto">
 <option value="" selected="selected">Seleccione...</option>
 <?php
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT id AS idProducto, titulo AS tituloProducto 
                      FROM productos WHERE operando = 1 
                      ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(titulo, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED) ASC, 
                         CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(titulo, '.', -2), '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED) ASC, 
                         CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(titulo, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED) ASC");
 while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    extract($r);
    ?>
    <option value="<?= $idProducto; ?>" 
           <?php 
           if($id_producto == $idProducto){ 
              echo"selected='selected'";
           } ?>
           ><?= $tituloProducto ?>
        </option>
    <?php
 }
 ?>
</select>
<label>Criterio de Cobro</label>
 <select name="tipo_cobro" class="input_form" required="required">
 <option value="0" <?php if($tipo_cobro == "0"){echo"selected='selected'";} ?>>Seleccione...</option>
 <option value="1" <?php if($tipo_cobro == "1"){echo"selected='selected'";} ?>>Fijo</option>
 <option value="2" <?php if($tipo_cobro == "2"){echo"selected='selected'";} ?>>Por Hora</option>
 <option value="3" <?php if($tipo_cobro == "3"){echo"selected='selected'";} ?>>Otro</option>
 </select>
 <div class="clear10"></div>
<label>Monto</label>
 <input type="text" name="monto" class="input_form" value="<?= $monto; ?>" >
 <div class="clear10"></div>
```

Comment: php is a server code, you can't expect to make a single change and expect it to update the results. all the inline php will occur before the page loads

Comment: but if i load the price and just filter it after the selection of both fields i believe it could happen

Comment: yes. if you plan on setting or passing the variable to the page before it loads. Is your price supposed to go in the query? I don't see it anywhere.